# when export radzen data grid to excel it export all rows but i need filtered rows only export to excel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, radzen

I work on asp.net core blazer server side . I face issue I can't export `radzen data grid` to excel after filter data on it .

so when page load list of Data source of `radzen data grid` it display 10 records

after that I make filter to any column on `radzen data grid` then it display 4 records so

when press button export to excel it export 10 rows meaning it export radzen data grid

before filter .

but correct it must export 4 rows to excel .

so How to export `radzen data grid` to excel after filter ridzen data grid ?

```
private async Task ExportToExcel()
    {
         ExceldatabaseData = databaseData.Select(p => new CopyExcelDatabaseClass
            {
                DBID = p.dbid,
                DBName = p.databaseName,
                ServerID = p.serverID,
                ServerName = p.serverName,
                Severity = p.serverity,
                BackupProcedure = p.backUpProcedure,
                Remarks = p.remarks,
                OwnerFileNo = p.ownerfilenumber,
                OwnerFileName = p.ownerfilename,
                IsActive = p.isActive

            }).ToList();
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.Commercial;
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DatabaseList");
            //worksheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(databaseData, true);
            worksheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(ExceldatabaseData, true);
            package.Save();
        }

        var buffer = stream.ToArray();
        var fileName = $"Database_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.xlsx";
        await JS.InvokeAsync<object>("saveAsFile", fileName, Convert.ToBase64String(buffer));
    }
java script function 
window.saveAsFile = (filename, bytesBase64) => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = filename;
    link.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + bytesBase64;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
};

  public class CopyExcelDatabaseClass
    {
        [DisplayName("DB ID")]
        public int DBID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("DB Name")]
        public string DBName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Server ID")]
        public int ServerID { get; set; }
        
        
        [DisplayName("Server Name")]
        public string ServerName { get; set; }
        
        public string Severity { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Backup Procedure")]
        public string BackupProcedure { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Owner File No")]
        public string OwnerFileNo { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Owner File Name")]
        public string OwnerFileName { get; set; }

        
        [DisplayName("Is Active")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    }
private IEnumerable<DatabaseClass> databaseData = Array.Empty<DatabaseClass>();
 private async Task RefreshList()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, config["API_URL"] + "Database/GetAllDatabaseDetails");
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        using var responsestream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        databaseData = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<DatabaseClass>>(responsestream);


    }
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await RefreshList();
    }
```